# how to add a node after the first node linear linked list c++

Tags: c++

I want to add a node after the first node in the linear linked list c++.

```
om = 202;
newNode = new node;
newNode -> data = 202;
newNode -> next = p -> next;
p -> next = newNode;
node * temp = head;
```

Comment: Suggestion: Give `node` a constructor. Something simple like `node(int newdata){ data = newdata; next = nullptr; }` can save a lot of pain hunting to find where you forgot to null terminate the list by always nulling next. Something a bit more complicated like `node(int newdata, node * linkto = nullptr){ data = newdata; next = linkto; }` gives you the ability to null or set the next link, but one of them happens no matter what. If you don't give anyone the opportunity to forget to do something important, whole families of bugs vanish from your programs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `head` is the head of the linked list, and also assuming that the code is written in a location where `head` can be modified.

```
newNode = new node;
newNode->data = 202;
if (head == NULL)
{
    newNode->next = NULL;
    head = newNode;
}
else
{
    newNode->next = head->next;
    head->next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: I want to ask also, how to remove the second node from the list.

Comment: @OmarAlhajri I recommend for that a new question.

Comment: @user4581301 I have to wait for 90 minutes to ask again.